# 6-node binary tree, exactly 2 have exactly 1 child

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, theory

Is such a binary tree possible? I've drawn out what I believe to be all possible iterations, and I cannot find a tree that satisfies these properties. Note that this is not a BST, so the values of the keys don't matter. There are countless with exactly 1 "single child" node, such as :

```
      a
     / \
    b   c
   /          //b is only such node
  d
 / \
e   f
```

And many with exactly 3 "single child" nodes:

```
          a
         / 
        b   
       /          //a, b, and d
      c
     / \
    d   e
   /
  f
```

Does such a binary tree exist (6 nodes, exactly 2 nodes with exactly 1 child)? If so, please provide an example.

Comment: Only the two single-nodes have a odd number of children, making for an even number of total links. Yet a 6 node tree has 5 edges, therefore it is impossible.

Comment: is there a reason you are looking for such a structure?

Comment: No practical reason. I'm just doing some reading on data structures, exploring properties of binary trees.

Answer (score 1):

This is an impossible structure to create with the standard binary tree containing 2 child pointers. If you had an nontraditional tree with 3 child pointers this would be possible.